# A/B test subject lines when using dynamic content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'd like to A/B test dynamic subject lines, however, I've been told this is only possible for the default version and isn't possible for the other versions. Is there any workaround to this, perhaps using AMPscript? Currently, for a newsletter, I have to upload four different Data Extensions and send four separate emails because of this limitation, which is incredibly time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to do an AB test within each of the four groups, which is totally doable. You can do a nested IF similar to the above.

Step 1: Split your data extensions's (DE) into two random groups - If you are using data filter activities in an automation to build right before send, the split can be done via SQL queries -- If you are manually uploading to SF each time I recommend adding an additional column (groupid) and using this method to add a value to your CSV marking them as either group 1 or 2 -- https://exceljet.net/formula/randomly-assign-people-to-groups

In your example you have 4 groups that you want to AB test, so I would take my data for each group and add 2 columns - groupname and testgroupid.  Lets say you have summer, fall, winter, spring as your groupname and testgroupid is 1 or 2 (50/50 split).

step 2: Set up the nested ampscript to reference each of those two levels:

```
set @groupname=groupname
set @testgroupid=testgroupid
if @groupname == 'summer' then
  if @testgroupid == '1' then
   set @subject = 'Summer Subject 1'
  else 
   set @subject = 'Summer Subject 2'
  endif
elseif @groupname == 'spring' then
  if @testgroupid == '1' then
   set @subject = 'spring Subject 1'
  else 
   set @subject = 'spring Subject 2'
  endif
elseif @groupname == 'fall' then
  if @testgroupid == '1' then
   set @subject = 'fall Subject 1'
  else 
   set @subject = 'fall Subject 2'
  endif
elseif @groupname == 'winter' then
  if @testgroupid == '1' then
   set @subject = 'winter Subject 1'
  else 
   set @subject = 'winter Subject 2'
  endif
ELSE
  set @subject='Default subject'
endif
```

This will let you put it all into one email which is great if you are good at analytics.  If you aren't. Then I recommend that you split your data extensions's (DE) into two random groups - adding an additional column (groupid) and using this method to add a value to your CSV marking them as either group 1 or 2 -- https://exceljet.net/formula/randomly-assign-people-to-groups.  Then sort and split into two uploads,  Testid1 (A) and testid2 (B) and doing 2 emails - one for A and one for B.  Then you would only need the simple ampscript, what was already provided:

FOR A

```
set @groupname=groupname
if @groupname == 'summer' then
   set @subject = 'Summer Subject 1'
elseif @groupname == 'spring' then
   set @subject = 'spring Subject 1'
elseif @groupname == 'fall' then
   set @subject = 'fall Subject 1'
elseif @groupname == 'winter' then
   set @subject = 'winter Subject 1'
ELSE
  set @subject='Default subject'
endif
```

FOR B

```
set @groupname=groupname
if @groupname == 'summer' then
   set @subject = 'Summer Subject 2'
elseif @groupname == 'spring' then
   set @subject = 'spring Subject 2'
elseif @groupname == 'fall' then
   set @subject = 'fall Subject 2'
elseif @groupname == 'winter' then
   set @subject = 'winter Subject 2'
ELSE
  set @subject='Default subject'
endif
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use AMPScript is the best way to create Subjects with dynamic content. You only have to add the A/B/n conditions declaring the variables in the HTML body of the email and call it from the Subject as usual `%%=v(@subject)=%%`.

In the email body:

```
SET @value_DE = Lookup('Name_DE','value_DE','subscriber_key',_subscriberkey)

VAR @subject 
if @value_DE == 'AAA' then
  set @subject = 'Subject 1'
   elseif @value_DE == 'BBB' then
     set @subject = 'Subject 2'
      elseif @value_DE == 'CCC' then
       set @subject = 'Subject 3'
        ELSE
         set @subject='Default subject'
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your response fromero. How exactly do I do this? (I'm not very skilled with AMPscript).

Comment: I just added the code in my first answer

Comment: Interesting formatting of if elseif and else statements. I would not format those like this and rather group them on the same level. That will help especially if you have more nested if else statements.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate your help. Does this method make it possible to A/B/C test for all other dynamic versions and not just the default version? What do I need to put into the Data Extension? Do I need to put the subject lines against each email address?

Comment: In the Data Extension, you should only have the values you need to compare to choose one subject or another. You can add the message to display in the subject manually replacing 'Subject 1', 'Subject 2', 'Subject 3' or 'Default subject'. This code will automatically show the proper message based on the values for each contact. In the Subject line of the email you only have to add %%=v(@subject)=%%

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. So am I putting AAA/BBB/CCC next to each subscriber in the Data Extension? And then adding the subject lines in the email body?

Comment: One field of the DE should contain the value you would like to compare to show one subject or another. The message to show is not in the DE but in the AMPScript code.

Comment: Thank you fromero. From the code above, am I just editing 'Name_DE' and 'value_DE' with the relevant data extension and column respectively?